# Fragment without a view crashes on configuration change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an UI where I need a `Fragment` to be displayed (with a view) in landscape mode but not in portrait mode. In portrait mode it should still be available but will display its result using `ListPopupWindow` instead.

I figured I could handle this by using the `<fragment />` tag for the landscape layout while creating the fragment programmatically if it wasn't started (in the case when we are in portrait).

This works fine as long as you start out in landscape, if you start in portrait where the fragment is created programmatically your application will crash when you rotate the emulator when it tries to attach the fragment to your layout:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Fragment  did not create a view.
>   at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4095)

The docs for `Fragment.isInLayout()` seems to hint that it should be able to handle it this way:

> Return true if the layout is included
>   as part of an activity view hierarchy
>   via the  tag. This will
>   always be true when fragments are
>   created through the  tag,
>   except in the case where an old
>   fragment is restored from a previous
>   state and it does not appear in the
>   layout of the current state.

So the question is how to do this correctly or if there is something I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

Seems like `isInLayout()` isn't behaving as it should currently as well. It returns false if you have added a `Fragment` to a container manually.

Also, if you add a `Fragment` manually to a container and then rotate (the device) to a layout that does not contain that layout it will crash:

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   view found for id 0x7f060011 for
>   fragment SearchFragment{4042f868 #2
>   id=0x7f060011 SearchFragment} at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:722)

Comment: I think there's some weirdness going on with fragments and configuration changes. I filed a bug report on something I found that's sort of like this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14796. The order of the fragment callbacks is not as documented when an app goes through a device rotation.

Comment: I had this issue quite some time ago. I don't know whether it is applicable to you, but in my case, adding `if (container == null) return null;` at the start of the `onCreateView()` fragment method prevents the view from being created, which prevents a `Fragment` loading if it is not needed on orientation change

Comment: @espi,
I tried that but my Fragment is still crashing, the stack trace never even hits any of my code either.  I have a hunch that it has something to do with my setting setRetainInstance.  Do you set that?

Comment: no, I had a lot of problems with retaining instances, and didn't really need to retain them so I just got rid of instances.

Comment: I read the documentation for `setRetainInstance` and it says it's not compatible with the back stack. I was using the back stack, so that was my problem.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

@hackbod: it would be great if you would throw one of those idiot-proofing exceptions if you add a fragment to the backstack with `setRetainInstance`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you come up with an answer to this?  I was having a similar problem, and managed to come up with a solution.  You can easily do what you are attempting as follows:

Create two different layouts one in the layout directory, one in the layout-land directory.  The one in the layout-land directory will be used in landscape mode.  As a placeholder, where you want your fragment to go, use s FrameLayout element, and id it, say with the id "my_fragment".  The layout in the layout directory should not contains any element with that id.

In your onCreate method, use findViewById(R.id.my_fragment) to locate the fragment placeholder.  If it exists, you are in landscape mode and should add your fragment (if it does not exist already): add(R.id.my_fragment, new MyFragment, "myFragment).  If you get null, you are in portrait mode and should not create the fragment.

Be very careful that you never replace a fragment created using a  tag, with one that you create dynamically in your program.  A fragment for which isInLayout returns true is a completely different beast, that one for which it returns false.  Their lifecycles are entirely different.  Replacing one with the other will lead to the dreaded IllegalStateException "Fragment did not create a view" problem.

-blake

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown of the problem. Been banging my head against this problem for half a day before I found your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can also be due to not having a lanscape layout for the fragment you are using. You might have one for the portrait and so your program runs fine but when you rotate your device, the OS probably looks for the view in the landscape folder and doesnt find the view so declares it as missing. Check that you have view both in the folder "layout" and "layout-land".

Comment: If there is no view in layout-land then Android just uses the one in layout, so this isn't the problem.