# Change orientation ANDROID

Tags: android, android-orientation

I need help.

My app still fails when the device orientation changes to landscape.

Whats the problem?

I have set in the Android manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`
and in the main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and my activities are fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Improper `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.main);` from `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Comment: We must know how the app fails? If the failure is a force close or other `Exception`, then you must show the stacktrace LogCat. If the LogCat shows an `Exception` caused in a line of your code, it will show the line number in one of your Java files. If possible, please show us that line of source code.

Comment: I had to change manifest and main activity dont rotation, but other activity working correctly

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. These things can be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are having the problem when your activity is being recreated.

Perhaps the solution might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672972/fragments-and-rotating-screen-problems)