# IllegalStateException: Link does not have a NavController set

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Android Navigation Component for Navigation. I have a LoginFragment which has a button to transition to SignUpFragment. On clicking the button I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{49d9bd1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 201,917-782,1061 #7f090172 app:id/signUpLink} does not have a NavController set
```

Here is my nav_graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="org.test.oe.app.core.auth.login.LoginFragment"
            android:label="login_fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_signUpFragment"
                app:destination="@id/signUpFragment" />
          
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

Here is the code in LoginFragment for Navigation -

```
binding.signUpLink.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_signUpFragment, null));
```

Here is extract from activity layout file for NavHostFragment -

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:name="android.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Comment: I also had got this issue. But in my case, the error is caused because I  placed the Button wrongly in _activity.xml file at the same level with "androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" fragment instead in _fragment.xml file. Now I moved the "Button" to _fragment.xml file and it's working. I'm not sure this can help you or not. Just sharing about the issue that I have been faced :-)

Comment: Make sure you use `fragment` element any not other Layout element

Comment: Inside onCreate() method to access navController use solution from below link
This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275009/fragmentcontainerview-using-findnavcontroller/59275182#59275182

Answer (score 128, accepted):

## UPDATED SOLUTION

Actually, Navigation can't find NavController in FrameLayout. So replacing `<FrameLayout>` with `<fragment>` will make it work .

Add the following inside the `<fragment>` tag -

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

After doing the changes, the code will look similar to this -

```
 <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
       app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation"
       app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Comment: This works fine, but will give a lint warning on the use of the <fragment> tag, stating that it should be replaced with a FragmentContainerView (although doing so will make your app crash).

Comment: android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"

Comment: @Peter I was able to solve this by upgrading gradle depedencies of material to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'`.

Comment: had an exception with FragmentContainerView, but works fine with fragment. Also when used FragmentContainerView it give lint warning that app:navGraph not set, but no such warning with fragment

Comment: Check this answer and its comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275182/421467

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275009/fragmentcontainerview-using-findnavcontroller/59275182#59275182

Answer (score 344):

## Officially recommended solution

Currently using the FragmentContainerView is not very friendly, you have to access it from the supportFragmentManager:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

In my xml my FragmentContainerView looks like this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    />
```

This has been tested with androidx navigation version `2.3.0`

I've removed the old answer because it has been clarified by Google devs that it is not the recommended solution anymore. Thanks @Justlearnedit, for posting a comment allowing me to update this issue.

Comment: see here for reason why this is probably good advice:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703451/fragmentcontainerview-as-navhostfragment

Comment: In the issue linked they discuss why you shouldn't use fragment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment15: *The Lint check is there exactly because you absolutely should switch over to FragmentContainerView in all cases.*

Comment: @Justlearnedit Thanks, this was not clear at the point when I posted this answer. Thanks for updating me, I've tested the recommended solution and made sure to update the post to reflect it.

Comment: "Method invocation 'getNavController' may produce 'NullPointerException'" so we always have to check for null before as well?

Comment: @Big_Chair Not sure what method you are referring to. NavHostFragment has a getNavController() function which is annotated with NonNull. Maybe you are using an older version of Navigation?

Comment: The recommended solution worked for me on Nav 2.3.3, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Rawa It is not working for me. I am testing with navigation `2.3.5`. I have seen many posts with this solution, Indeed Android documentation states like you had posted.

Comment: This also works when you receive null after minified or ofuscation. Try this.

Comment: what about extension? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190134/activity-findnavcontroller-extension-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks for saving my time , Ref here as well https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: `supportFragmentManager` is now deprecated, **you should use `childFragmentManager`** instead (and not the "parent" one).

Answer (score 69):

After doing some research I found [this Issue also on Google's bugtracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973).
So here's the official solution in Java:

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavController navCo = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

and here in Kotlin:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: Works perfectly with Java and FragmentContainerView. (nav_version = "2.3.0")

Comment: this is working perfectly but, removed my toolbar and added one with back button, any idea how to fix this please?

Answer (score 49):

The reason is that the fragment view isn't available inside the `Activity.onCreate()` method if you're adding it using `FragmentContainerView` (or just a `FrameLayout`). The proper way to get the `NavController` in this case is to find the `NavHostFragment` and get the controller from it. See the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973) and the [explanation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment2).

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...

   val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_container_view_id) as NavHostFragment
   val navController = navHostFragment.navController
}
```

**Don't use** `<fragment>` instead of `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` as some other answers suggest. See the [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment15) from the Google team in the issue I mentioned above.

> You should always use FragmentContainerView. There are absolutely other fixes around window insets and layout issues that occur when a fragment's root layout is directly within other layouts such as ConstraintLayout, besides the underlying issues with the  tag where fragments added via that tag go through lifecycle states entirely differently from the other Fragments added to the FragmentManager. The Lint check is there exactly because you absolutely should switch over to FragmentContainerView in all cases.

There's also an [announcement](https://amryousef.me/new-in-androidx-fragment#fragmentcontainerview-vs-framelayout) from AndroidDevSummit 2019 which explains why `FragmentContainerView` was introduced, and another thread on SO about the difference: [<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView> vs  as a view for a NavHost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58737769/4858777)

Comment: what about extension? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190134/activity-findnavcontroller-extension-doesnt-work

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was done by android studio...

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

The above code is the working code that was replaced as shown below by a warning!

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Just replace `<FrameLayout>` With `<fragment>` and replace `android:name="org.fossasia.openevent.app.core.auth.login.LoginFragment"` with `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"`

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem.
So,instead of this,

`binding.signUpLink.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_signUpFragment, null));`

I used my `NavHostFragment` to find the `NavHostFragment`:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment navhost = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
                NavController c = NavHostFragment.findNavController(navhost);
                c.navigate(R.id.firstFragment);


            }
        });
```

`fragment2` is `navhostfragmentID`.

Answer (score 6):

In Java try this below line:

```
Navigation.findNavController(findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)).navigate(R.id.first_fragment);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the view of fragment such as onViewCreated

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

    binding.signUpLink.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_signUpFragment)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the following error:

> MainActivity@9ff856 does not have a NavController set on 2131230894

I was using Bottom Navigation View:

The following worked for me:

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment)
val navController = navHostFragment?.findNavController()
if (navController != null) {
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## use onPostCreate() in MainActivity

Instantiate your `lateinit var navController` in `onPostCreate()` instead of `onCreate()` like so:

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_fragment_container)
}
```

make sure your in your xml you are using:
`<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView />`

Answer (score 0):

A weird thing happens to me, below code snippet was working on normal flow from Fragment1 to fragment2, but after coming to fragment1 and on again navigate fragment2, this was throwing the "Navigation controller not set for the  view" error.

```
    binding.ivIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Openfragment2(v);});

private void Openfragment2(View view) {
    Navigation.findNavController(binding.ivIcon).navigate(R.id.fragment2);

}
```

Here problem was in view, in findNavController need to pass the  onclicked view.

```
private void Openfragment2(View view) {
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fragment2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue just now, but i was sure about my code and then realized that i have changed the location of the fragment from under the main package to another folder

so 
i solved the issue with Build-> clean then Build ->make project to let the IDE to change its Directions class

Comment: I have _cleaned_, _build_ and _rebuild_ but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I change my code

```
val action =
        StartFragmentDirections.actionStartFragmentToLoginFragment()
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
```

In `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 0):

this code should work properly for kotlin

```kotlin
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_loginFlow_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
navController.navigate(R.id.to_dictionaryDownload1)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case (I was using `BottomNavigation`), in `findNavController` I was adding `Framlayout` Id! you should add the `fragment` Id like this:

**in my xml:**

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_orders"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bnv_main"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="false" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

**in Kotlin class:**

```
private val navOrdersController by lazy {
        mainActivity.findNavController(R.id.nav_orders).apply {
            graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.main_navigation_graph).apply {
                startDestination = startDestinations.getValue(R.id.action_history)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

private lateinit var binding : ActivityNewsBinding

lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)
    binding = ActivityNewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val newsrepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
    val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsrepository)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)

    
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer for FragmentViewContainer**

Make sure you have

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

instead of the fragment you want as start fragment.
(Start destination is defined in the Nav Graph).

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you have to override both onCreatedView and onViewCreated in all the fragments
my code:
`

```
     <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fl"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I forget to add the start destination

```
app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home"
```

res ==> navigation ==> mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem. My scenario was when i click on image in recycler view go to another fragment. below code was giving error [image]

When i change this code to below code it works well. NO ERROR
[image]