# Navigation Component: pass safeArgs from activity to a fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I have two graphs, so the first graph move from one fragment to an activity passing safeArgs to the activity.

```
val action = MyFragmentDirections.actionMyActivity(arg1, arg2)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
```

Now in the second, I want to pass these arguments from `MyActivity` to a fragment which belongs to this activity.

I can get the args:

```
val args = MyActivity.fromBundle(intent.extras)
```

The problem is there is not a `Directions` file for this activity, so I can't pass the arguments.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the arguments to the `startDestination` of your second activity's navigation graph?

Comment: The fragment from the MainActivity navigate to a DetailActivity which has a fragment (this is the home fragment, or startDestination of the DetailActivity graph). Can you check my answer to know if it is the correct way to solve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Navigation 1.0.0-alpha07](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#october_29_2018) fixed the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110300470) for passing arguments to the start destination of a graph.

To use this, you'd need to:

1. Remove the `app:navGraph` attribute from your `NavHostFragment`
2. Call `findNavController(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment).setGraph(R.navigation.your_graph, intent.extras)`

Using the `R.id` of your `NavHostFragment` and `R.navigation` that you previously had on your `app:navGraph` tag. By passing the arguments into the `setGraph` call, your starting destination will get the arguments directly, without calling `navigate` again (which would, by default, create a new instance of the destination on your back stack - not what you want).

Comment: findNavController() is asking me for a view, I used findViewById. Can you edit it to findNavController(findViewById(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment)) please? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using the `-ktx` dependencies (you really, really should if you're doing Kotlin code). The correct replacement if you aren't using the Kotlin extensions is `Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.your_nav_host_fragment)`

Comment: @Ian The asker mentioned that he passes data to the second activity via Safe Args. If the second activity is in a separate module (that doesn't depend on the first module), is it still possible to use Safe Args? I'm seeing that the generated Args class is created in the first module, so the second activity doesn't have access to it. Thanks!

Comment: Woah, nvm. I spoke too soon. I can just grab the extras from the intent.. awesome!

Comment: Any way to use SafeArgs with this?

Comment: setGraph didn't work for us because on re-attach of container fragment (MyActivity in example), the destination fragment is always recreated, instead of re-attached. Solution: navHostFragment.arguments = requireArguments(); and in destination fragment: arguments = requireParentFragment().requireArguments()

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using nav version 2.3.5, and I am facing the same issue. Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: I get an 'Activity does not have a NavController set on' error when trying to use `setGraph()`.

Comment: FindNavController doesn't seem to work. You need to use this code to get the navcontroller to call setGraph on:

`val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60597670/812013

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is recommended, but it is working:

```
val args = MyActivity.fromBundle(intent.extras)
navController.navigate(R.id.myActivityFragment, args.toBundle())
```

Comment: Using fragment's args: 
`val bundle = bundleOf("message_tip" to "") 
findNavController().navigate(R.id.helpFragment, HelpFragmentArgs.fromBundle(bundle).toBundle())`

Answer (score 0):

It work for me

1. Remove the app:navGraph attribute from your NavHostFragment

   ```
       <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
       android:id="@+id/video_view_fragment"
       android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="false"
       app:defaultNavHost="true"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
   ```
2. and call

   ```
       navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
       .findFragmentById(R.id.video_view_fragment) as NavHostFragment

   navHostFragment.navController.setGraph(R.navigation.video_navigation, intent.extras)
   ```