# Android Espresso does not have a NavController set Error

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-espresso-recorder

I am trying to test a fragment in my navigation architecture and my test is as follows:

test.kt

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
internal class AddingAccountTest{

@get:Rule
var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>
        = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Before fun loadCorrespondingFragment(){

}

@Test fun checkThatAllFieldsInFormAreEmpty(){
    // Create a TestNavHostController
    val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_drawer_main)

    // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<AddAccountFragment>(Bundle(), themeResId = R.style.Locky_Theme)

    // Set the NavController property on the fragment
    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
    onView(withId(R.id.Account_Name)).check(matches(isEnabled()))
}
}
```

But when i run it, i am getting the follow errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{65be158 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0129 app:id/cl_layout} does not have a NavController set
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:118)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
at com.th3pl4gu3.locky_offline.ui.main.add.account.AddAccountFragment.observeBackStackEntryForLogoResult(AddAccountFragment.kt:89)
at com.th3pl4gu3.locky_offline.ui.main.add.account.AddAccountFragment.onViewCreated(AddAccountFragment.kt:72)
```

The error is occurring in my AddAccountFragment.kt on line 89 which contains this code:

AccountFragment.kt

```
val navBackStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.Fragment_Add_Account)
```

This code is used to get backstack entry data as follows:

```
private fun observeBackStackEntryForLogoResult() {
    // After a configuration change or process death, the currentBackStackEntry
    // points to the dialog destination, so you must use getBackStackEntry()
    // with the specific ID of your destination to ensure we always
    // get the right NavBackStackEntry
    val navBackStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.Fragment_Add_Account)

    // Create our observer and add it to the NavBackStackEntry's lifecycle
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME
            && navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.contains(KEY_ACCOUNT_LOGO)
        ) {
            /*
            * Update the logo
            */
            viewModel.logoUrl =
                navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ACCOUNT_LOGO)!!

            navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.remove<AccountSort>(KEY_ACCOUNT_LOGO)
        }
    }
    navBackStackEntry.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

    // As addObserver() does not automatically remove the observer, we
    // call removeObserver() manually when the view lifecycle is destroyed
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            navBackStackEntry.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    })
}
```

Can someone help me on why this error is occurring ?

Comment: Can someone please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IllegalStateException: Link does not have a NavController set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502269/illegalstateexception-link-does-not-have-a-navcontroller-set)

Comment: I tried all these, i am still getting this issue. Any idea why i am getting this ?

Answer (score 3):

```
titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
}
```

`onFragment` is called after the fragment has moved to the resumed state. It's too late as you are using `NavController` in `onCreateView` (according to the stack trace you posted).

To fix this problem, you need to set the `TestNavHostController` way sooner, just after fragment's view has been created:

```
val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<AddAccountFragment>(
    Bundle(),
    themeResId = R.style.Locky_Theme
).also { fragment ->
    fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
        if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
        }
    }
}
```

To learn more, visit [Test Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#test_navigationui_with_fragmentscenario) guide.