# FragmentContainerView as NavHostFragment

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

Seems like using the `FragmentContainerView` doesn't work right out of the box?

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_app" />
```

Here's my code using `fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc01` and I'm just always getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity ...MainActivity@797467d does not have a NavController set on 2131296504
```

Just using `<fragment>` works and AFAIK, it's just supposed to be replaced by `FragmentContainerView`.

Am I missing something or was anyone able to use `FragmentContainerView` as a `NavHostFragment`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Due to this bug-report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973

This is the only way (currently):

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

(Java):

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment =
    (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Comment: surely better just to use `fragment`rather than worrying about having to remember to use this workaround? We were seeing crashes but only for some users, weird...

Comment: @hmac In the issue linked they discuss why you shouldn't use fragment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment15: *The Lint check is there exactly because you absolutely should switch over to FragmentContainerView in all cases.*

Comment: does not show anything. It's weird I am stuck with using <fragment>!

Comment: what we have to do with navController, because the variable is unused

Answer (score 50):

**August 2020 update**

Here is the solution recommended by [the official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate).

Kotlin version:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Java version:

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

I quote the doc:

> **When creating the NavHostFragment using FragmentContainerView** or if
> manually adding the NavHostFragment to your activity via a
> FragmentTransaction, attempting to **retrieve the NavController** in
> onCreate() of an Activity **via Navigation.findNavController(Activity,
> @IdRes int) will fail**. You should retrieve the NavController directly
> from the NavHostFragment instead.

---

The bug-report reported by *Ove Stoerholt* will not be fixed. You can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973) the "Won't Fix (Infeasible)" status.

Comment: While the original task was tagged as "Won't Fix (Infeasible)", they did link to another task so they might plan to fix the issue after all: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143145612

Answer (score 10):

What I did was to wait for the `NavHostFragment` to inflate its view:

Kotlin:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

// Set up the form and list.
setContentView(R.layout.activity_xxx)

// Set up navigation - action bar and sidebar.
/// Let the navigation view check/uncheck the menu items.
nav_view.post { // wait for NavHostFragment to inflate
    val navController = findNavController()
    nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}
```

Java8 (with lambda):

```
navigationView.post(() -> { // wait for NavHostFragment to inflate
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(navItemSelectedListener);
});
```

Comment: I had used `<fragment>` to avoid the bug. But I was troubled another unknown error. So I found this @Pnemonic's late answer and tried it in order to use `<FragmentContainerView>`. The problem has been cleared, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when using kotlin:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Just add it to

`setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)`

Answer (score -7):

using `android:name` instead of `class`. works.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    ...
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. As the docs states:
`FragmentContainerView can also be used to add a Fragment by using the android:name attribute.`
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView