# Activity does not have a NavController set on

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation

I basically set up 3 fragments for my bottom navigation view with all linked to activity.xml

*activity.xml* where I put fragment tag.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="599dp" />
```

My Activity.java code (specifically):

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

The problem now is that if I run that same java code using fragment tag in xml, it runs well but suggests I use `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView(linters)` but on using `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`, it displays the error in the Logcat.

> Activity does not have a NavController set on

I've seen a lot of similar errors and fixes for that on this site like [FragmentContainerView as NavHostFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703451/fragmentcontainerview-as-navhostfragment)

But the problem now is that most of them post Kotlin codes and the few java codes I tried didn't work for me

or who can translate this code to java:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: android studio can do the conversion from kotlin to java and vice versa automatically

Comment: @cagney well it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the Nav Controller using Java like this:

```
final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

And then you setup your bottom navigation like this:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

Answer (score -5):

Try using include:
1.) Create a content_main using navigation host frag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Using include in activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.Activity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is not from my layout.xml but my activity.java