# Navigation Component not working with FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

> I have tried multiple ways to achieve navigation

Have a [look at this](https://github.com/IMDroidude/GalleryAppArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/gallery/app/architecture/MainActivity.kt) class and for full source [See this](https://github.com/IMDroidude/GalleryAppArchitecture)

[**activity_main.xml**](https://github.com/IMDroidude/GalleryAppArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

Android studio recommend **FragmentContainerView** to be used for `Navigation` purpose. I simply want to show two fragments one is the `PhotosFragment` and the other is `PhotoDetailFragment` using **Navigation component**.

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/photosFragment">
    <fragment android:id="@+id/photosFragment"
        android:name="gallery.app.architecture.ui.photos.PhotosFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_photo">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_photosFragment_to_photoDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/photoDetailFragment" app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/photoDetailFragment"
        android:name="gallery.app.architecture.ui.photos.PhotoDetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_photo">
        <argument android:name="imageUrl" app:argType="string"/>
        <argument android:name="userName" app:argType="string"/>
        <argument android:name="tags" app:argType="string"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I simply want to show two fragment one with PhotosFragment(List of photos) and on Click on any photo . Move to PhotoDetailFragment.

Latest code is pushed to Github along with it's link share above.When I test fragment individually, it's working correct. but navigation component not working as it should be.

**Issue Resolved**
MainActivity with Navigation doesn't work with binding.

Comment: There is no question.... and you'll need to add plugins & dependencies, too.

Comment: I have added all plugins and dependencies as per google guideline and share latest project link in question as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FragmentContainerView as NavHostFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703451/fragmentcontainerview-as-navhostfragment)

Comment: I think you're not inflating the `View`, else it would pick up `id/nav_graph` from XML.