# Fragment displaying a grey field

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I am still a bit new to fragments in android studio but I was wondering if this is usually how fragments are displayed as on the phone. It appear as a grey background above my activity, as shown in this image: https://gyazo.com/9d5569718c5092debfeaab1c631b0046

This is my MainAppActivity code:

class MainAppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainAppBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainAppBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMainApp.toolbar)

    binding.appBarMainApp.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_app)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_app, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_app)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

Any buttons or similar seems to also be affected by it.
Is this normal or is it some sort of bug?

My content_main_app, this is my home set fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_app">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main_app"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment 1:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

XML layout fragment 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Fragment 2:

```
class HobbiesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHobbiesBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val hobbiesViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHobbiesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.mainTitle
        hobbiesViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

XML layout fragment 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/beige1"
    tools:context=".ui.Hobbies.HobbiesFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HOBBIES"
        android:textColor="@color/blueMix"
        android:textSize="38sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.097"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.064" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Fragment 3:

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textGallery
        galleryViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

XML layout fragment 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Layout containers (like `LinearLayout` and `ConstraintLayout`) are usually transparent unless you set a background on them. You look like you have a semi-opaque area that's even overlaying the app bar, which isn't where your fragment should be. Post yr layout XMLs

Comment: I updated my code to include the layout in xml. This is the first screen that appears. It does contain a navigation drawer as well!

Comment: You should post your fragment's XML too (that's probably what has a background defined somewhere) but I think that `fragment` declaration should be a `FragmentContainerView` like here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment The idea with the container is the Navigation component swaps different `Fragment`s in and out of it as you navigate around the app. Also that `layout_behavior` might be causing the "drawing over the app bar" thing - and the recommended approach is to put a `Toolbar` right in the layout (see that link again)

Comment: I added the 3 fragments as well as you suggested! I tried to change the <Fragment to <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView, however this ended up blocking the starting up of the app!!

Comment: yeah you'll probably need to fix some other stuff if you do that. Those aren't the layout XML files btw, so we can't see what properties you're setting on anything

Comment: I posted now all 3 xml file layouts as well. Will try again to create a fragmentContainerView for mainAppActivity and see why it crashed when I launch the app. If you find anything on the xml files, please let me know!

Comment: Update!! I managed to solve the problem by using your article about <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView and by using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703451/fragmentcontainerview-as-navhostfragment. The only problem that still remains is that the grey field is still persistent over the fragments, even though I set a background for a fragment.

Comment: @cactustictacs I managed to solve the issue. Thanks anyway for the feedback, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of messing around in android studio I finally found out what was giving me a grey background, covering the main fragment. I had to go into my main activity ( mainAppActivity in my case ) and delete the material divider (as seen in the image). It solved the problem for me.[image]