# NavController no current navigation node after device rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am making app, which supports different device orientations. Navigation is carried out by Android Jetpack's Navigation. App main screen for landscape orientation is present below. It is list wrapper fragment (it is `NavHostFragment`, it is added to activity's layout in `fragment` tag), wrapper includes list fragment (`fragment`) and details fragment (`FrameLayout`). Portrait orientation is similar (wrapper and list in it, details is accessible throw navigation).

[image: App main screen]

My problem is after I change device orientation I get exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node

First version of my layout with mocked data worked fine, the error appears after I add ROOM to my app, new order and update order fragments. It is a pity, I cannot localize source of error more exact.

List wrapper code

```
class OrderListWrapperFragment : RxFragment() {

    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    var selectedOrderId: Long = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val bundle = savedInstanceState ?: arguments
        bundle?.let {
            selectedOrderId = it.getLong(EXTRA_ORDER_ID)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders__list_wrapper, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initializeToolbar(toolbar, getString(R.string.orders_title), false)

        newOrderButton
            .clicks()
            .subscribe {
                findNavController()
                    .navigate(R.id.action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderNewFragment)
            }
            .addTo(disposable)

        childFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(callback, false)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        childFragmentManager.unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(callback)

        disposable.clear()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState.putLong(EXTRA_ORDER_ID, selectedOrderId)
    }

    private val callback = object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {

        private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

        override fun onFragmentResumed(fm: FragmentManager, fragment: Fragment) {
            super.onFragmentResumed(fm, fragment)

            if (fragment is OrderListFragment) {
                fragment
                    .selectedItemIdChanges
                    .subscribeBy(onNext = {
                        selectedOrderId = it
                        if (orderDetailsContainer != null) {
                            childFragmentManager.commit {
                                replace(
                                    R.id.orderDetailsContainer,
                                    OrderDetailsFragment.newInstance(it)
                                )
                            }
                        } else {
                            findNavController()
                                .navigate(
                                    R.id.action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderDetailsFragment,
                                    bundleOf(EXTRA_ORDER_ID to it)
                                )
                            selectedOrderId = 0
                        }
                    },
                        onError = {
                            Log.d("detailView", it.toString())
                        })
                    .addTo(disposable)

                val orderId = selectedOrderId
                if (orderId != 0L) {
                    if (orderDetailsContainer != null) {
                        childFragmentManager.commit {
                            replace(
                                R.id.orderDetailsContainer,
                                OrderDetailsFragment.newInstance(orderId)
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        findNavController()
                            .navigate(//exception throws here
                                R.id.action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderDetailsFragment,
                                bundleOf(EXTRA_ORDER_ID to orderId)
                            )
                        selectedOrderId = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFragmentPaused(fm: FragmentManager, fragment: Fragment) {
            super.onFragmentPaused(fm, fragment)

            if (fragment is OrderListFragment) {
                disposable.clear()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val EXTRA_ORDER_ID = "EXTRA_ORDER_ID"
    }
}
```

My navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/orderListWrapperFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderListWrapperFragment"
        android:name="com.mtgshipping.app.orders.orderList.OrderListWrapperFragment"
        android:label="OrderListWrapperFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/orders__list_wrapper">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderDetailsFragment"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderNewFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderNewFragment"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderListWrapperFragment_to_orderUpdateFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderUpdateFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.mtgshipping.app.orders.orderDetails.OrderDetailsFragment"
        android:label="OrderDetailsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/orders__order_details">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderDetailsFragment_to_orderUpdateFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderUpdateFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderNewFragment"
        android:name="com.mtgshipping.app.orders.orderNew.OrderNewFragment"
        android:label="OrderNewFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/orders__order_new">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderNewFragment_to_orderListWrapperFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderListWrapperFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderUpdateFragment"
        android:name="com.mtgshipping.app.orders.orderUpdate.OrderUpdateFragment"
        android:label="OrderUpdateFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/orders__order_update">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderUpdateFragment_to_orderListWrapperFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderListWrapperFragment"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I made some debug in `NavController`, it showed in line 746 `NavDestination currentNode = mBackStack.isEmpty() ? mGraph : mBackStack.getLast().getDestination();` after device rotation `mGraph` is `null`, other private fields is also `null`. Maybe something prevents `NavController` to initialize properly. I can provide layouts and other code, if it will be need.

Comment: I fixed navigation by updating Navigation Component to version 2.2.1. See this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738512/4568679

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to Slav's comment, he was right. I updated navigation module to 2.2.0 `navigation_version = '2.2.0'` in app's module `build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

After doing this problem is no longer appears, looks like that was a bug in navigation.

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807361/still-have-error-no-current-navigation-node-even-after-using-navigation-2-2-1

Comment: According maven page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.navigation/navigation-fragment the lates version is 1.0.0. How do you use the 2.2.0 version?

Comment: @IrvingLóp This is old package, I use ktx version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-fragment-ktx

Comment: @sarah you probably forgot to change android.arch to androidx in the library name, basically change "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx" to ""androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:" and the same thing for the other navigation library.

Answer (score 11):

You can also fix it like this. 
In your host activity in manifest adding this atribute:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
```

But the best way is change your dependencies for navigation from:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Comment: This was my issue, old dependencies. I think these "android.arch" dependencies are depreciated for "androidx"

Comment: I guess if you're using `android.useAndroidX=true` option in your build, then you need `androidx.navigation` instead of `android.arch.navigation`.

Comment: Changing from "android.arch" to "androidx" solved my issue, many thanks

Comment: Yes this was helpful!  I tried updating to 2.2.0 as suggested in the answer above, but I also had to switch from android.arch to androix.  I'm fowlling some google codelabs that need to be updated!

Comment: Also  in your project build.gradle change dependencies classpath to `"androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"`

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I was inflating graph only when `savedInstanceState == null`

Changing it to inflate every time `onPostCreate` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was the version of lifecycle dependency

```
"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version
```

version '2.2.0' cause the problem, I returned to use '2.1.0'

```
lifecycle_version = '2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this exception after removing `app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"` in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions fixed my issue.

**I fixed it by including my nested graph into the main graph.**

I have a `nav_main` which includes a `nav_sub_1`. 
`nav_sub_1` also includes another sub graph, `nav_sub_2`
When I tried to start my activity by setting `nav_sub_2`, the `IllegalStateException` occured

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node

But this would not happen by setting `nav_main` or `nav_sub_1`.

My main graph `nav_main` looks like this:

```
<navigation
    <fragment...>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_sub_1
<navigation/>
```

and `nav_sub_1`:

```
<navigation
    <fragment...>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_sub_2
<navigation/>
```

**I included nav_sub_2 in nav_main and the issue was fixed!**

```
<navigation
    <fragment...>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_sub_1
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_sub_2
<navigation/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fragment had the wrong parent. Changing this

```
   class MyFragment: DynamicNavHostFragment() ...
```

to this

```
   class MyFragment: Fragment() ...
```

Fixed that issue