# Foldables Cause Crashes in Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin

I using navigation graph and I use

```
val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainToPaymentFragment(viewModel.paymentDetails!!)
binding.PayBills.findNavController().navigate(action)
```

To navigate, my problem was is that whenever I change the app to landscape from portrait and from portrait to landscape it crashes on navigation, I made the application portrait only and it worked but now I am having problem with foldable devices

```
2020-02-12 11:40:12.980 32594-32594/com.batelco.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.batelco.mobile.debug, PID: 32594
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:750)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:907)
    at com.batelco.mobile.login.LoginFragment$onCreateView$2.onClick(LoginFragment.kt:64)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set a graph id on the nav host fragment?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I already did, <navigation android:id="@+id/main_graph" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After time of searching a found a guy is having the same problem as mine
Here: [NavController no current navigation node after device rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970818/navcontroller-no-current-navigation-node-after-device-rotation)

The problem was to be a bug with navigation at version 2.1.0 and lower
The solution is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148951/9278341

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738512/9278341