# still have error no current navigation node even after using navigation 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970818/navcontroller-no-current-navigation-node-after-device-rotation) but it doesn't solve my issue

so I navigate to next destination using this code

```
 val nextDirection = CreateEventNameFragmentDirections.actionToCreateEventType(userKM, newEvent)
 findNavController().navigate(nextDirection)
```

but it crash after I rotate the device with error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node

i update the gradle using this

> ```
> implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1'
> implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1'
> ```

but it still doesn't work , it still crash. what should I do ? here is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {

    private lateinit var navController : NavController



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        // Initial Setup views
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)



        setupBottomNavMenu()
        setupActionBar()


        // Add Listeners
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)




    }





    private fun setupBottomNavMenu() {
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    private fun setupActionBar() {

        generalToolbar.title = ""
        searchToolbar.title = ""
        searchWithBackButtonToolbar.title = ""

        // set up top hierarchy destination
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_home,
            R.id.destination_search,
            R.id.destination_user_control,
            R.id.destination_create_event,
            R.id.destination_inbox,
            R.id.destination_verified_user_control)
        )

        if (include_toolbar_general.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            setSupportActionBar(generalToolbar)
            generalToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        } else if (include_toolbar_search.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            setSupportActionBar(searchToolbar)
            searchToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        } else if (include_toolbar_search_with_back_button.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            setSupportActionBar(searchWithBackButtonToolbar)
            searchWithBackButtonToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        }



    }

    override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {

        setUpShadowInToolbar(destination)
        setToolbarVisibility(destination)
        setBottomNavigationViewVisibility(destination)

    }

    private fun setUpShadowInToolbar(destination: NavDestination) {

        // set up shadow below the toolbar
        if (destination.id == R.id.destination_search || destination.id == R.id.destination_keyword_result) {
            searchToolbar.elevation = 0.0f
        } else {
            generalToolbar.elevation = 4.0f
        }

    }

    private fun setToolbarVisibility(destination: NavDestination) {

        if (destination.id == R.id.destination_authentication ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_loginUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_registerUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_change_password ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_finished_info ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_photo_view ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_1 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_2 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_3 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_report_event_confirmation ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_user_control ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_verified_user_control

        ) {

            include_toolbar_general.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search_with_back_button.visibility = View.GONE


        } else if (

            destination.id == R.id.destination_search

        ) {

            include_toolbar_general.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            include_toolbar_search_with_back_button.visibility = View.GONE


        } else if (

            destination.id == R.id.destination_keyword_result

        ) {

            include_toolbar_general.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search_with_back_button.visibility = View.VISIBLE



        } else {

            include_toolbar_general.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            include_toolbar_search.visibility = View.GONE
            include_toolbar_search_with_back_button.visibility = View.GONE


        }


        setupActionBar()



    }





    private fun setBottomNavigationViewVisibility(destination: NavDestination) {

        if (destination.id == R.id.destination_authentication ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_loginUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_registerUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_choose_user_location ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_change_password ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_finished_info ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_photo_view ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_1 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_2 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_on_boarding_3 ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_report_event_confirmation
        ) {

            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        } else if (

            destination.id == R.id.destination_home ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_search ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_user_control ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_verified_user_control ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_inbox

        ) {

            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else {

            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        }


    }

    fun setBottomNavigationMenu() {

        // this method will be called in home, loginUsingEmail and Authentication fragment


        val user = sharedPrefManager.loadUserData() ?: return

        if (user.verified && bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.destination_verified_user_control) == null) {
            // set different bottom navigation menu for verified user, if bottom_navigation_verified_menu have NOT been inflated yet
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            bottomNavigationView.menu.clear()
            bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_verified_menu)

        } else if (!user.verified && bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.destination_verified_user_control) != null) {

            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            bottomNavigationView.menu.clear()
            bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_menu)
        }


        // when trying to clear the menu and then inflate with the new one above
        // it will create weird menu item transition
        // thats why we hide the bottom navigation view and then show it again by using delay below

        Handler().postDelayed({
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }, 200)





    }


}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are overwriting your NavHostFragment on rotation or something

Answer (score 7):

I finally can solve it by using this

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
```

Comment: For me, the version 2.2.2 works as well, but the crucial change was the dependency groupId – `android.arch.navigation` had to be replaced with `androidx.navigation`. I guess it depends on whether you're using `android.useAndroidX=true` option in your build.

Answer (score 3):

I was extending my fragment with `NavHostFragment` changed it to `Fragment` and it started working fine

Comment: This happened to me too. But I was extending my fragment with my own class like `class BaseFragment: Fragment`. Works fine after removing it

Answer (score 0):

This is an incompatible androix plugin problem. Slav rightly mentioned if you are using useAndroidX=true then, pls use version 2.2.0 onwards

```
// Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```