# How do I fix MainActivity does not have a navcontroller?

Tags: android, kotlin

I just got my code to compile and when I try to start the app I receive the error. I'm currently trying to setup RecycleView for my class project. My goal is to make the RecycleView show content sorta like the reddit mobile app. I thought my RecycleView named "scrollview1" had a navcontroller setup. Not sure why I'm getting this output

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.john.chanapi/com.john.chanapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.john.chanapi.MainActivity@1850938 does not have a NavController set on 2131230866
```

My MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.john.chanapi

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new, R.id.nav_rising,
                R.id.nav_top, R.id.nav_inbox, R.id.nav_message
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You've included a link to your `content_main` xml, but your code is inflating `activity_main` - what does that XML look like?

Comment: I edited the post and included the activity_main.xml

Comment: You need to define fragment in activity_main. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502269/illegalstateexception-link-does-not-have-a-navcontroller-set

Comment: @JohnJoe I tried following that thread and came up with this fragment. **<fragment
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />**.  I inserted it into activity_main. App still crashes. I'm don't think i'm doing this correctly.

Comment: same error ????

Comment: I fixed it. This is the fragment I made **<fragment
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />**

Answer (score 60):

To be on the safer side, **(within an Activity)** avoid using `findNavController(Int)` to initialize a `NavController` instead initialize it from `NavHostFragment` as shown

```kotlin
val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_host) as NavHostFragment
val navController: NavController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: @IanHannibalLake on the Google team's original answer can be found in [FragmentContainerView using findNavController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275182/2253682).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful

Answer (score 6):

use simple `<fragment>` tag instead of
`<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>`

Comment: the best answer for me without typing any extra code.

Answer (score 0):

`val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)`

because `R.id.scrollview1` will find the UI component that is `RecyclerView`,

not `NavController`

Comment: How would I go about to fix this? Do i replace the ID in the parentheses with a navcontroller?

Comment: @johnkasarda Delete all kind of  `NavController`, and search how to use `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreate views are not inflated yet. When you call findNavController it will fail.

One solution is to override the onViewCreated method and move the code after setSupportActionBar into onViewCreated.

Sample

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener {}

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new, R.id.nav_rising,
            R.id.nav_top, R.id.nav_inbox, R.id.nav_message
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```