# FragmentContainerView using findNavController

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation

I'm using Android Navigation Component with bottom navigation, lint gives a warning about replacing the `<fragment>` tag with `<FragmentContainerView>` but when i replaced, `findNavController` is not working it gives me error about it does not have a NavController set on

Fragment

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Activity

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_classes, R.id.navigation_schedule, R.id.navigation_settings
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: replace `FragmentContainerView` with `fragment`

Comment: I don't want to use `fragment`, there is a warning if I replace

Answer (score 174, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973), when using `FragmentContainerView`, you need to find the `NavController` using `findFragmentById()` rather than using `findNavController()` when in `onCreate()`:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

This is because `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)` relies on the Fragment's View to already be created which isn't the case when using `FragmentContainerView` (as it uses a `FragmentTransaction` under the hood to add the `NavHostFragment`).

If you are using [Fragment 1.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.4.0) or higher and [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), you can simply this considerably by using the [`getFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView#getFragment()) method:

```
val navController = binding.container.getFragment<NavHostFragment>().navController
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but Can I use `findNavController` if it's not in onCreate?

Comment: Yes, outside of `onCreate()` the Fragment's view will be created so it'll continue to be fine to call `findNavController()`

Comment: This answer did not work inside `Fragment.onCreate()`. Says `NavController is not available before onCreate()`.

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue @EpicPandaForce. I tried the above solution unsuccessfully. I will look for a working sample to link to here.

Comment: If you're in a Fragment, you wouldn't be using anything here, you'd be using `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` / `findNavController()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I'm attempting to implement within an Activity as outlined above. I will create a quick sample app to replicate the issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I've created a StackOverflow post and sample app outlining the issue regarding a null _NavHostFragment/NavController_, [_Null NavHostFragment/NavController with FragmentContainerView_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827683/null-navhostfragment-navcontroller-with-fragmentcontainerview)

Comment: Technically this is in combination with `FragmentContainerView`, and probably expected even.

Comment: I figured out the issue in my [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61828944/2253682). I was not creating a parent navigation graph to define in the `FragmentContainerView`. This threw me off since the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)'s `FragmentContainerView` does not define a parent navigation graph.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz - yes, the `NavigationAdvancedSample` uses completely independent `NavHostFragment` instances to support multiple back stacks as per the [description of the sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples#samples); it uses a completely different style and functionality from any of the documentation.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Works for me.

Comment: I like references to magic variables like `supportFragmentManager`

Comment: @Chuck - that isn't a "magic variable" - that's how Kotlin code refers to the `getSupportFragmentManager()` API of `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: `navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2` and `FragmentContainerView` works together by defining `name` on XML:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost

Comment: implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'  Code you shared not working on the kotlin . On Demo example it's working fine. can you please help me. I am finding from 4 hrs. When I click on next tab. nothing happened. My parent layout is constraint layout

Comment: only answer which worked for me. I was trying to access NavController through findNavController in onCreate() method which was causing app crash.

Comment: @ianhanniballake like you said Im using nav-frag 2.7+ and viewbinding, So i used the second method like you mentioned but it seems not working can you please tell where I gone wrong 



`val navController = binding.sampleHostFragment.getFragment<NavHostFragment>()
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)`

logcat error Fatal Exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.navigation.NavController androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.getNavController()' on a null object reference

Comment: @ianhanniballake as per the issue you quoted this seems working but its deprecated  `Handler().post {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.sampleHostFragment)
            binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
        }`
handler is deprecated

Comment: @NabilNazar - that is absolutely the wrong thing to do anyways. The code in this answer is the only thing you should be using. You'll want to create your own question with the minimal code needed to reproduce your issue if it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 11):

Replace this line:

```java
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

with

```java
NavController navController = getNavController();
```

Where `getNavController()` looks like this:

```java
    // workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973
    @NonNull
    private NavController getNavController() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        if (!(fragment instanceof NavHostFragment)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity " + this
                    + " does not have a NavHostFragment");
        }
        return ((NavHostFragment) fragment).getNavController();
    }
```

Comment: for me this is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

On top of the accepted answer, a little shortcut what could be used is:

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostMain)?.findNavController()
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Add in your build.gradle (Module: App) this line

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2"
```

and use this in activity

```
val navController = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_id_nav_host_fragment)
            ?.findNavController()
```

and in fragment

```
val navController = findNavController()
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problen with extension:

```
fun FragmentActivity.findFragmentContainerNavController(@IdRes host: Int):NavController {
    try {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(host) as NavHostFragment
        return navHostFragment.findNavController()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Activity $this does not have a NavController set on $host")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use simple `<fragment>` tag instead of `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler way to @friederbluemle's answer.
An assertion check should suffice.

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment 
    = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
assert navHostFragment != null : "navHostFragment not found";
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer -

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
```

as NavHostFragment

```
val navController = navHostFragment.navControllermenus.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: What's `navControllermenus`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 different ways:

If you use `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` tag in xml, it is as follows:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navigationController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navigationController = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
            ?.findNavController()!!
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navigationController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navigationController, null)
    }
}
```

[image]

Use is not recommended. If you use `<fragment>` tag in xml, it is as follows:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navigationController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navigationController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navigationController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navigationController, null)
    }
}
```

Note: It should be added to your `build.gradle` file.

```
....
 // Navigation
    val nav_version = "2.7.6"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")
....
```

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`
to `<fragment>`, and it worked for me.

Comment: This defeats the point of the question, the user doesn't want to use `<fragment>`...