# You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, orientation-changes

I have bottom Navigation also I'm replaced the `<fragment>` tag with `FragmentContainerView` it gives me error about it does not have a NavController set on, then i was posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275009/fragmentcontainerview-using-findnavcontroller/59275182?noredirect=1#comment104757841_59275182) question and fixed the problem, but I got this below error when orientation is changed and selecting item in Bottom Navigation

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()

FragmentContainer

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" /
```

finding fragment

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_classes, R.id.navigation_schedule, R.id.navigation_settings
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is fixed as per the [2.2.0-rc03 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.2.0-rc03):

> `NavHostFragment` now correctly restores the graph after a configuration change when used with `FragmentContainerView`. ([b/143752103](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143752103))

So make sure you are using `2.2.0-rc03`.

Comment: sir, could you please help me with this one ? I can't find a method after using `2.2.0-rc03` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598241/setupwithnavcontroller-method-for-toolbar-no-longer-available

Answer (score 12):

You'll get this same error if you are like me and forget to add to your `FragmentContainerView`

```
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

Comment: this is what worked for me. the other solutions did not work.

Answer (score 7):

use Navigation UI's latest vesion:

```
// navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0-alpha02"
```

it fixed on new versions

Comment: add classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha02"

Answer (score 5):

Follow this link to fix this issue
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation
In simpler terms upgrade your dependencies to the ones below in app module

```
def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha05"
```

// Java

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

// Kotlin

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

// Dynamic Feature Module Support

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
```

// Testing Navigation

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
```

in project module under dependencies if you are using safe args

```
  def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha05"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

that fixed my issue..