# Null NavHostFragment/NavController with FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bottomappbar

## Expected

Create bottom app bar navigation using Navigation UI's `BottomNavigationView` and `FragmentContainerView` similar to the sample app *[NavigationAdavancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)*.

Note, *NavigationAndvancedSample* app does not appear to use the same implementation as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation) as it has a workaround implementation using the custom extension method `setupWithNavController`.

## Observed

Null `NavHostFragment` when creating the `BottomNavigationView` in the *MainActivity.kt* with a `FragmentContainerView`.

***The reproducible error and full code sample is available in the [BottomNavigationViewSample](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/BottomNavigationViewSample) repository.***

### Error

> 2020-05-15 12:39:19.117 18747-18747/com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample, PID: 18747
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample/com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample.MainActivity}: **kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment**
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
>           at com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>   2020-05-15 12:39:19.132 18747-18747/com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18747 SIG: 9

### Implementation

1. Create a navigation graph for the first view, *home.xml*, to show in the `BottomNavigationView` under *app > res > navigation*.

   a. When prompted to *Add Project Dependency*, select *OK*.

   b. Add `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }` to *build.gradle (:someAppModule)* to enable inline bytecode for the `AppBarConfiguration`.

   c. Add a fragment to *home.xml* to display in the `BottomNavigationView`.

*home.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
</navigation>
```

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
}
```

2. Create a menu for the `BottomNavigationView`, *bottom_nav.xml*, under *app > res > menu*.

   a. Add string values for the menu `id` and `title`.

   b. Add vector drawable for the menu `icon`.

*bottom_nav.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_home"
            android:title="@string/title_home" />
</menu>
```

3. Add the `FragmentContainerView` and `BottomNavigationView` to *MainActivity.kt*'s *activity_main.xml* layout.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

4. Enable the `BottomNavigationView` in *MainActivity.kt*.

   a. Create `AppBarConfiguration`. *See: Update UI components with NaviationUI > [AppBarConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration)*

   b. Create the `NavHostFragment` and `NavController`. *See: StackOverflow solution for [FragmentContainerView using findNavController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275182/2253682)*

   c. Set the action bar navigation.

   d. Set the `BottomNavigationView` navigation. *See: Update UI components with NavigationUI > [Bottom navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation)*

*MainActivity.kt*

```
package com.example.bottomnavigationviewsample

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.home))

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. Create the `NavController` with `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_container)` as outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation).
2. Implement a `fragment` view instead of `FragmentContainerView` in *activity_main.xml*.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem.
My mistake was that I did not enter the correct ID for navigation tag in navigation files.
Note that the ID must be equal to the ID of the menu items.

in navigation file (navigation/home.xml):

```
<navigation
android:id="@+id/home" ... >
```

and in menu file (menu/bottom_nav.xml):

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/home" ... />
```

Comment: That was the issue, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Add a parent navigation graph for the `BottomNavigationView` menu items.

The full sample code is included within [BottomNavigationSample](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/BottomNavigationViewSample).

1. Create a parent level navigation graph for the menu fragments. Note, this is not reflected in the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) architecture pattern which has three separate navigation graphs without a parent navigation graph.

This can be accomplished with one parent navigation graph and fragments or nested navigation graphs for each menu item. Nested navigation graphs are good because each sub-flow can be organized within the nested graph.

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">
    <include app:graph="@navigation/home" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/saved" />
</navigation>
```

2. Add the parent graph using `navGraph` in the `FragmentContainerView`.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. Enable the `BottomNavigationView` in *MainActivity.kt*.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.home, R.id.saved))

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```