# Why addOnDestinationChangedListener not called in activity

Tags: java, android

Why `addOnDestinationChangedListener` not working, I want to know when the fragment change.

**Error**

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.test.MainActivity@7cc430 does not have a NavController set on 2131296700
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/view_821"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.view_821);
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
            Log.w("ABC", "A");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FragmentContainerView using findNavController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275009/fragmentcontainerview-using-findnavcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked with me**

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.view_821);
NavController navController = Objects.requireNonNull(navHostFragment).getNavController();
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) - > {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is that `MainActivity does not have a NavController set`

I don't think that is how you get access to the `NavController` in activity. Try this:

```
val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.view_821) as NavHostFragment

navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
```

Let me know if it fixed it for you :)

Comment: supportFragmentManager not found

Comment: are you using this code inside your `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes I got this message Cannot resolve method 'supportFragmentManager' in 'MainActivity'

Comment: does your `MainActivity` extend `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: yes but I don't know why it can't find it, I'll try it with new project