# Using navigation component with bottom navigation bar by using FragmentContainerView tag

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I have already looked this question: [FragmentContainerView using findNavController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275009/fragmentcontainerview-using-findnavcontroller) about this problem. But however I stiil couldn't solve the problem. It never opens other fragments. I thought maybe it is because of view binding but I tried to do it again without using view binding. It doesn't open still.

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                navHostFragment.navController.popBackStack()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />
    

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav_graph_main

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentLibrary">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLibrary"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.FragmentLibrary"
        android:label="fragment_library"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_library" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTransaction"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.FragmentTransaction"
        android:label="fragment_transaction"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transaction" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAccount"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.FragmentAccount"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentAccount_to_changeSignatureFragment"
            app:destination="@id/changeSignatureFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentAccount_to_securityFragment"
            app:destination="@id/securityFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentAccount_to_helpFragment"
            app:destination="@id/helpFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentAccount_to_termsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/termsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/changeSignatureFragment"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.ChangeSignatureFragment"
        android:label="fragment_change_signature"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_change_signature" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/securityFragment"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.SecurityFragment"
        android:label="fragment_security"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_security" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/helpFragment"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.HelpFragment"
        android:label="fragment_help"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/termsFragment"
        android:name="com.project.biosec.TermsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_terms"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_terms" />
</navigation>
```

menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/feed_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_library"
        android:title="@string/library" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/messages_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment"
        android:title="@string/transactions" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:title="@string/account" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please include your `nav_graph_main.xml` and your `menu.xml` files. The IDs in those need to match.

Comment: i just added @ianhanniballake. And I did not know that IDs in those xmls need to match. I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Setting up bottom navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation):

> Note: Setting up bottom navigation requires that you also set up your navigation graph and menu xml as described in [Tie destinations to menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer).

That section specifically states that the `android:id` of your destination in your navigation graph XML file needs to match the `android:id` of the menu item in your menu XML file.

In your case, your navigation XML uses `android:id="@+id/fragmentLibrary"`, `android:id="@+id/fragmentTransaction"`, and `android:id="@+id/fragmentAccount"`, so your menu items should change to use those same IDs.

Comment: how to avoid recreation of the fragment on each bottom nav click?