# Activity.findNavController() extension doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

This works

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

But this doesn't

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity MainActivity does not have a
> NavController set on 2131231020

What could be a problem?

`FragmentContainerView` in activity layout XML:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Comment: can you show your FragmentContainer XML ?

Comment: Oh I didnt saw the 1st code snippet. I faced the same problem previously as well. It seems this `Activity.findNavController()` is not working somehow. I was forced to use the first code snippet as you do.

Comment: But `Fragment.findNavController()` is working fine. Very weird lol

Comment: It seems to work if using `fragment` instead of `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` but Google recommends to use `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`