# App is installed but not launching on my device

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation

I am currently working on an android web browser development and when I install the app on my android device through USB the app installs but does not run and shows this error, how should I fix this?

The error encountered is:

```
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cognibrowse/com.example.cognibrowse.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.cognibrowse.MainActivity@6a0ba67 does not have a NavController set on 2131231034
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3762)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3929)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8302)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.cognibrowse.MainActivity@6a0ba67 does not have a NavController set on 2131231034
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:50)
    at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:31)
    at com.example.cognibrowse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8159)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1330)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
    ... 12 more`your text``
```

Comment: This seems to be possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502269/illegalstateexception-link-does-not-have-a-navcontroller-set

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your NavController

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: I was able to add the controller the app runs well.