# Jetpack Compose: Error Navigation graph has not been set for NavController

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack

I encountered an error when I ran my application

my code snippet

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "list"
    ) {
        composable("list") {
            JetSubmisAppDesign(navController = navController, users = UserData.user)
        }
        composable("detail/{userName}") { backStackEntry ->
            val userName = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("userName")
            val user = UserData.user.firstOrNull { it.name == userName }
            if (user != null) {
                DetailScreen(user = user)
            } else {
                // Handle user not found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun JetSubmisAppDesign(
    users: List<UserModel>,
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(users) { user ->
            UserListItem(user = user, onItemClick = {
                navController.navigate("detail/${user.name}")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

For the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.chaidar.jetsubmisapp, PID: 20848
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/detail/Achmad Zaky }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController androidx.navigation.NavHostController@ab63d61.
```

I want to navigate my compose application but why does this error occur? I don't understand the error

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50502269/8681) answer your question?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work in your code. Could you please add some detail and where and how you started?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the whitespace in userName argument.

```
detail/Achmad Zaky
```

Try encoding.

```
   val userName = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(user.name.toByteArray())
   navController.navigate("detail/${userName}")
```

Also, at the receiving side, don't forget to decode.

```
val userName = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your run configuration is set to your app and not a compose preview